# Transferring of pre-tax 401K to Roth IRA: do states charge taxes on the transfer?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira

Transferring a pre-tax 401k to a Roth IRA incurs paying ordinary income taxes. In CO they charge an additional 5%. Are there states that do not charge the additional tax (e.g., Ohio, North/South Carolina, or DC)?

Answer (score 1):

Converting a qualified 401K to a Roth is an income event so you have to pay income taxes on the amount coverted.  In Colorado, the flat income tax rate is 4.63% regardless of income.  I assume that is what you mean by the additional 5%?

Any state without income tax will allow you to convert Roth state income tax free as they don't have a state income tax.

States without income tax are:  Alaska, Florida, Nevada, South Dakota, Texas, Washington and Wyoming.

Typically people are advised to only convert into a Roth during a low income tax liability year.  One of those factors would be being a resident of a non-income tax state.

You might be better off putting your 401K money into a rollover IRA until the time it is more advantageous to roll into a Roth.